# GetServiceProjectReferences task could not From MSBuild

Tags: azure, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to build my Service Fabric application from powershell using "msbuild" command. I am getting the following exception.

> I have the build components installed for VS 2017 at C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin

I updated the ToolVersion in project to 15.0. But im still getting the same error.

Other than powershell any option to deploy service fabric application ( Not in azure)?

> Project file contains ToolsVersion="14.0".
>
> > This toolset may be unknown or missing, in which case you may be able
> >     to res olve this by installing the appropriate version of MSBuild, or
> >     the build may have been forced to a particular ToolsVers ion for
> >     policy reasons. Treating the project as if it had ToolsVersion="4.0".
> >     For more information, please see http://g
> >     o.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=291333.
> >     C:\Directory\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.5\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio
> >     .Azure.Fabric.Application.targets(94,5): error MSB4062: The
> >     "GetServiceProjectReferences" task could not be loaded from  the
> >     assembly
> >     C:\CodeBase\Directory\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.6.5\build\Microsof
> >     t.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.BuildTasks.dll. Could not load file or
> >     assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14 .0.0.0,
> >     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> >     dependencies. The system cannot find the file s pecified. Confirm that
> >     the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
> >     dependencies are available , and that the task contains a public class
> >     that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
> >     [C:\CodeBase\Directory\Directory.sfproj] Done Building Project
> >     "C:\CodeBase\Directory\Directory\Directory.sfproj" (default targets )
> >     -- FAILED.

Comment: According to the error message, there is still have anything related to the old toolsversion. Have you tried to create a new project to build it with Service Fabric application to check if still have this error? If you still want to find the reason for this error, you may need to provide us you project file, so that we could check it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Instead of creating the package from powershell, "Create package" option from visual studio solution explorer worked for me without any issue. I'm still not sure why power shell command is not working.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, could you please share some more detail steps how did do that with powershell?  Some more steps so that we could reproduce this issue, it is not easy to find the reason only based on the error message :(.

Comment: From the solution folder of the Fabric application I ran the "msbuild" command. Then I got initial error saying "Version" is not a valid attribute in project files. So after removing the version attribute from nuget package references in project files. I got the above exception. Even with the visual studio(2017) default template application also, I got this exception. I have selected Stateless Aspnet Core 2.0 from the templates.

Comment: What is your MSBuild command line? Where you call the MSBuild.exe? From this path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin?

Comment: No, from my service fabric application solution file path.I am running the powershell command from the my application path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168902/discussion-between-leo-liu-msft-and-kokirala-sudheer).